# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery<> does not contain a definition for 'Include'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm developing the Music Store sample app with ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework and WCF.

in the database layer just want to extract  retrieve Genre and its Associated Albums from database.

so used this method for it , used the Stored Procedure 'GetAllGenres' to get all the Genre

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllGenres
AS
BEGIN       

   SELECT [GenreId]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Description]
  FROM [dbo].[Genres]

END
GO
```

the method accessing the above Stored Procdure is

```
public static Genre BrowseGenre(string genre)
        {
            using (MusicStoreEntities db = new MusicStoreEntities())
            {
                return db.Database.SqlQuery<Genre>("GetAllGenres").Include("Albums").Single(g => g.Name == genre);
            }
        }
```

**I'm getting an error of below**

System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include'

**how to fix it?**

Comment: missing import `using System.Data.Entity;`?

Comment: How would that Include "Albums"? Instead why don't you simply try db.Genres.Include("Albums").

Comment: @Justcode still same error

Comment: @CetinBasoz yes I could use db.Genres.Include("Albums") but just trying to use the Stored Procedure calling method of db.Database.SqlQuery<Genre>("GetAllGenres")  , is there is way for it?

Comment: Well, you can't do `Include()` outside EF `DbContext` classes, but you can join a materialized `DbContext` with `DbRawSqlQuery` results and then use `Select` with `Single` extension methods.

Comment: SqlQuery doesn't have Include method. It is an unnecessary stored procedure anyway, when there is simply db.Genres. Instead of an SP you could have created a TVF which would make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final Conclusion since SqlQuery doesn't have Include method**

```
public static Genre BrowseGenre(string genre)
        {
            using (MusicStoreEntities db = new MusicStoreEntities())
            {
                //return db.Database.SqlQuery<Genre>("GetAllGenres").Include("Albums").Single(g => g.Name == genre);
                return db.Genres.Include("Albums").Single(g => g.Name == genre);
            }                
        }
```